# Weird passing php string to javascript sometimes not work

Tags: php, string

how i what it to work:
goal: make a album viewer without reload the page, with a img html element, change img SRC dynamically with javascript, but image url's stored in php variables and what copy to javascript array.
Problem: example have album where have 17 picture, if i echo in php then $i count from 1-17 but in javascript count to 2-12 and 15-17 so ignore 1,13,14 etc. have no ideea why because no difference in data, so DataPicId[13] is undefined but 15th index or 12th index got value normally.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($SQLpic))
{
$i=$i+1;
$PicId=$row['id'];
$Url=$row['url'];
$Desc=" ".$row['description'];
$UpUser=$row['uploader'];
$Update=$row['udate'];
echo"<script>
nr=Number('".$i."');alert(nr);
DataPicId[nr]=Number('".$PicId."');
DataPicUrl[nr]='".$Url."';
DataPicDesc[nr]='".$Desc."';
DataPicUser[nr]=Number('".$UpUser."');
DataPicDate[nr]='".$Update."';
alert(DataPicUrl[nr]);
</script>";
$ThumbUrl=GetNameOnly($Url);
echo "<div id='PicBoxOut'>
<div id='PicBoxIn' onclick=SelectSrc('".$i."');>
<a href='javascript:void(0);'>
<img src='".$ThumbUrl."' border='0'></a>
</div></div>";
```

Comment: Most likely an issue with code breaking because of missing quoting of characters. Take your browsers development console and check 1. for any output at runtime and 2. the code of the script generated. Probably it is invalid.

Comment: Can you (1) format the code to be somewhat readable, (2) show the complete loop, (3) remove unrelated code, (4) show the resulting client-side JavaScript?  We can't really execute this and debug it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the generated html / javascript, I would guess that your variables are breaking your javascript. That could be for example a single quote in the description of a photo.

To make sure that you output valid javascript, it is better to send your complete row-set to javascript as json and build your html in javascript using that json.

So something like:

```
<?php
// Note that normally you would have done this already in a controller
// and not when you are outputting html
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($SQLpic))
{
  $rows[] = $row;
}
?>

<script>
var json = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>,
    object = JSON.parse(json);

// now `object` will contain all your rows in a javascript object / array

</script>
```